# Using the Broadcom AFBR-S50 with Arduino

Tags: sensors, library, spi, ir, firmware

I'm trying to interface with a Broadcom [AFBR-S50MV85G](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optical-sensors/time-of-flight-3d-sensors/afbr-s50mv85g) ToF sensor over SPI using an Arduino, which is complicated by the fact that the provided library and reference application is written for Cortex M0-based NXP microcontrollers. The documentation says that implementing the SPI, IRQ, Debug and Timer interfaces would allow use with other platforms, but it doesn't explicitly state which functions require implementations, or if all of them do, and it's not demarcated within the source code either.

The documentation lists the available command words, but no register addresses, which I believe are used by the platform-independent compiled libraries that come with it. This leaves me with no way to interface manually over SPI, meaning that my only choice appears to be to attempt to implement the platform drivers myself, which will probably take me a significant amount of time.

Is there something else I should try before sinking time into something that may not give me results? Has anyone here used this sensor before, and if so, could you point me in the right direction?

P.S.: The documentation I'm referring to is included in the SDK provided in the downloads section of the product page, and I'm not sure I'd be allowed to rehost it somewhere else in order to link it here.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Broadcom. Unless you're a multi-billion dollar global technology giant, you won't get **** out of them.  And then only with multiple layers of NDAs.

Comment: @Majenko Yeah, I'm starting to realize that after trying to contact them directly. I couldn't get anything out of them - I tried going through Digi-Key, and even they got stonewalled. :/

Comment: Eben Upton had the same problem with the Pi. That's why graphics on the Pi are so crap - Broadcom won't give anyone the information they need to use the GPU. And he *works* for Broadcom! Everything on the Pi has basically been reverse engineered from other sources.  Broadcom are dicks.

Comment: @Majenko Wow, that's incredible, did not know that. Clears up a lot, actually. *sigh* Hopefully someone else has made the same mistake I did and had better luck.

Answer (score 2):

I recently looked into this again, and it turns out that Broadcom had released a [porting guide](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AFBR-S50-PG) for this library in August 2020 (nearly a year after I originally posted this question) that should prove useful to anyone trying to make use of this sensor. It's for the STM32 platform, not Arduino, but it's the most detail Broadcom has provided with regards to this product, and should provide a starting point at least.

I happen to have access to the Nucleo board used in the guide, but I had some issues with following it in some cases due to some differences in the SDK file/directory structure. I did eventually get a passing build out of it, but couldn't get anything out of the sensor itself, which means that I either did something wrong, or had damaged the sensor in my earlier attempts to interface with it; at the time of my last attempt, I was leaning towards the latter. I don't think I'll be revisiting this unit any time soon, so hopefully others will have better luck. And if anyone does get it working, please do report back; I'm curious to know if I'd actually be able to use this thing if I were to buy another one.

P.S: I'm not marking this as answered because a) my question was technically for the Arduino, and b) I haven't been able to confirm that this is working.

Comment: I switched from Arduino to a Blackpill (STM32F411CE) and was able to get the sensor to work. I had to rebuild a STM32CubeIDE project based on their example, as I couldn't get theirs to work. The HAL tests they provide were particularly useful. The sensor works great, even in direct sunlight, unlike others such as the VL53L0X.

Answer (score 2):

I also have been digging for information about the AFBR-S50MV85G and similar sensors for the past week.

Well, I am trying to port it to ATxmegas (ICs that are similar to those ATmegas used in the Arduino Family), but I decided to post my findings here because this is the first forum topic that I have found about this sensor family.

As Joseph mentioned, Broadcom has released a porting guide to Arm devices, but it does not help at all when it comes to porting to other microcontrollers.
Additionally, the minimum requirements of this lib according to Broadcom's [porting guide](https://broadcom.github.io/AFBR-S50-API/porting_guide.html) are:

> Minimum memory requirements:
> RAM: 8kByte (4kByte Heap + 4kByte Stack)
> ROM/Flash: 128 kByte

Because of that and other facts, I also conclude that it is not possible to port the available libraries to 8-bit microcontrollers nor develop a new one due to the lack of description about the SPI register structure.